# Factorise: $a^4-b^4+c^4-d^4-2(a^2c^2-b^2d^2)+4ac(b^2+d^2)-4bd(a^2+c^2)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Factorise:  $a^4-b^4+c^4-d^4-2(a^2c^2-b^2d^2)+4ac(b^2+d^2)-4bd(a^2+c^2)$.

My working: $(a^4-2a^2c^2+c^4)-(b^4-2b^2d^2+d^4)+4ac(b^2+d^2)-4bd(a^2+c^2)$
$=(a^2-c^2)^2-(b^2-d^2)^2+4ac(b^2+d^2)-4bd(a^2+c^2)$
$=(a+c)^2(a-c)^2-(b+d)^2(b-d)^2+4ac(b^2+d^2)-4bd(a^2+c^2)$

Solution: $(a+c+b+d)(a+c-b-d)(a^2-2ac+c^2+b^2-2bd+d^2)$

My question is: it is not hard to work backward from the solution and see how it works, but how could I proceed from my stage of working if we were not told about the solution? And how many ways are there to factorise this expression?

Many thanks!

Comment: You could fix $b=c=d=1$ and try to find values $a_i$ of $a$ for which the polynomial becomes zero. Then you know that $a-a_i$ is a factor is the polynomial. Because you expect the factorization to be nice (up to a certain point), you can guess that $(a+3)=(a+b+c+d)$ and (after some other values for $b$, $c$ and $d$) that $a-1=a+c-b-d$.

Comment: And counting the number of terms yields $0$, so you know at least one of the factors must have $0$ terms in total. (The number of terms in $ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ is $a+b+c$ in this case.)

Answer (score 0):

Last question first:  If you take integers coefficients and factor all the way down to irreducibles (no further factoring possible), then up to ordering, there is only one factorization.

Factoring this one by hand is all about recognizing differences of squares.  The hints are "$a^4+c^4$" with "$a^2+c^2$" and "$a^2c^2$" and likewise for $b$ with $d$.  The general method is "you don't want to know".  If there's interest, I can describe an entirely automatable method that no human should ever undertake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't quite understand what you meant by "you don't want to know". Are you saying that we should not think reversely from the solution to the question?

Comment: No.  I mean the method is entirely mechanical, infeasible by hand, generally infeasible by computer, and filled with opportunities for error.